# Map Sencha Touch model hasMany association to List items

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a hasMany relationship between employee-favorites. I can get the store to populate the data structure, but my question is there a way to have the child element (the favorites in this case) be the items for the list item template.

I can use tpl for statement but then all the items are in one list item element. I need one per item element.

Comment: Can u put the code here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution for this. The only way to show associations, as you pointed out, is to use a custom `tpl` which loops through them.

This is because Lists are Store backed components, and stores currently only support 1 type of model.

Comment: I think what is best for me is if I drill down to the favorites in a separate store and map my view to that store instead.  Thanks for clarifying though.